# Yaml version of `kubectl autoscale deployment`

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I run the command `kubectl autoscale deployment xxx --min=1 --max=3 --cpu-percent=80` given that no deployment by the name `xxx` exists, I can receive an error which indicates that the autoscaler could NOT be created since the deployment name is invalid (does not exists) and this is desirable.

However, when I write the same in a yaml file:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
name: autoscaler-test
spec:
scaleTargetRef:
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  name: xxx
minReplicas: 3
maxReplicas: 10
targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

I receive a message indicating that the autoscaler has been created successfully.

> horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/autoscaler-test created

This is of course undesirable as I have a problem here: Has the autoscaler been `Successfully` created and will it really work (did I provide the right deployment name).

Since I am not a kubernetes pro and have been working with it for only a week, I have this question, is the yaml file configuration even correct or on in other words is it equivalent to the command line version? If not, how can I re-write the command like version in forms of a yaml file?

I need to convert it to a yaml file because it would be much cleaner in a CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: the command you are trying is correct , please update the output of `kubectl get deployments <deployment name> ` and `kubectl autoscale deployment <deployment name > --min=1 --max=3 --cpu-percent=80`

Comment: @confusedgenius: Of course they are correct! The problem is that `xxx` as deployment does not exist so I EXPECT an ERROR. The yaml version does NOT output any error.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated the above scenario. You are facing the issue while running the “auto scale” command  because you might be missing to create the deployment.  To create the deployment use the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f  xxx.yaml
```

and then run the autoscale command.

After the autoscale command run the following command to get the YAML of your HorizontalPodAutoscaler.

```
kubectl get hpa xxx -o yaml
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question.

Comment: @Arnold Zahrneinder I have edited my answer. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You didn't understand the question right! I would like to get an error!! It's not why I get the error!! The problem is that if the deployment does NOT exist, I do not get an error.

Comment: It's exactly the opposite of what you are thinking. It should show an error but it does NOT

Comment: Yes as you said I have checked it again If you use configuration file auto scaling will be done but it will not work as the deployment is not created.